# What is the best way to handle different injectable implementations?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

So I have an abstract Java Class and a few implementations (5 in my case).

It looks something like this:

```java
public abstract class AbstractAbst {
    String someCommonString;

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    public AbstractAbst () {
    }

    public AbstractAbst (String someCommonString) {
        this.someCommonString = someCommonString;
    }
}

public class Abst1 extends AbstractAbst {
    public Abst1() {
        super();
    }

    public Abst1 (String someCommonString) {
        super(someCommonString);
    }
}

public class Abst2 extends AbstractAbst {
    public Abst2 () {
        super();
    }

    public Abst2 (String someCommonString) {
        super(someCommonString);
    }
}

// ... And 3 more
```

Now in my class where I want to use those classes I do it like so:

```java
public class AbstUser {
    @Inject
    Abst1 abst1;
    @Inject
    Abst2 abst2;
    // ... And 3 more

    public AbstUser () {

    }

    public doSomething {
        abst1.someCommonString = "test";
        abst2.someCommonString = "test";
        // ... And 3 more

        switch(someDecision) {
            case 1:
                abst1.doSomethingInAbst1();
                break;
            case 2:
                abst1.doSomethingInAbst1();
                break;
            // ... And 3 more
        }
    }
}
```

But that cant be the best way. Unfortunatley I am pretty new to JavaEE, so I can't think of a better way.

My Questions:

- Is there some way of Injecting constructor parameters, so that I can
  omit the `abst1.someCommonString = "test"` part, because its actually
  a lot more bulk, because its not only one parameter.
- Can I somehow
  inject the abstract class and determine at run time which
  implementation I want to use?

Comment: As far as I know, your injected types need to be resolved at the time the bean is constructed.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen So how would you go about a problem like this?

Comment: There's not enough context to make that call. WIth the information provided: don't inject anything and just construct the required type at runtime. If you have other ways to qualify what needs to be injected, you can take a look at [`Instance`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html).

Comment: I need to inject it though, because the abstract class injects something too. Or can you instantiate an object of a class that injects something, without injecting that class?

Comment: You can do funky stuff like that using the [`BeanManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html).

Comment: Yeah, but that seems really hacky to me. Doesn't it? @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Not really... I mean, it's part of the API...

Comment: There are a lot of classes in the API, that are an absolute shit show to use. I would like to make this program simple to understand. At the moment it is simple, but very bulky. With `BeanManager` (at least what I understand on how to use it), it would be complex and bulky. Can you maybe write a quick answer with how you think I should use it? @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Are `Abst1`, `Abst2`, etc supposed to be subclasses of `Abst`? Are they intended to be `abstract` as well? Are you trying to inject a single implementation of `Abst` into `AbstUser` that is supposed to be determined at runtime according to some algorithm?

Comment: @SteveC Yes they are subclasses, no they are not intended to be abstract aswell. (I forgot to change the class header when copying - updated my question). Yes I want to choose at runtime which implementation of Abst I want to use

Answer (score 0):

By putting @Inject over your overloaded constructor you can define it as an injection point and parse your parameters through it:

```
public abstract class Abst {
String someCommonString;

@Inject
Logger logger;

public Abst () {
}
@Inject
public Abst (@Named("myString") String someCommonString) {
    this.someCommonString = someCommonString;
}
}


public class AbstUser {
@Produces
@Named("myString")
public String getMyString() {
return "test";
}
```

In the getMyString function you return the string that should be put where @Named("myString") is used

Comment: but be careful: A bean can only have one injectable constructor.

Comment: How would I inject the `someCommonString` from the Class that injects `Abst1/2/...` with this contructor?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you trying to build:

```java
public class AbstUser {
    @Inject
    AbstractAbst abst;

    public doSomething() {
        abst.doSomethingInAbst();
    }

}
```

where `AbstractAbst` is declared as you provided, albeit with an abstract method to be invoked:

```java
public abstract class AbstractAbst {

    @Inject
    @Named("myString")
    String someCommonString;

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    public abstract void doSomethingInAbst();

    ...

}
```

and you want to determine the actual sub-type of `AbstractAbst` that is injected at runtime.

The way to do this is to make use of [javax.inject.Qualifier](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/inject/Qualifier.html) in conjunction with a *producer*.

The *qualifier* is used to remove the ambiguity that you would otherwise have when the type of the injection point is a super-type.

For the sake of argument let's say that you want to compute the concrete type of `AbstractAbst` that is to be injected. This would be a "computed AbstractAbst`. Therefore we create a Qualifier for this purpose:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface Computed {
}
```

**It is common for qualifier names to be adjectives.** I would expect that you could come up with a better domain specific adjective rather than "Computed".

Now we need to produce a `Computed` `AbstractAbst` object. Producer methods are often written in factory classes, but they can be added to any kind of bean. We inject [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) instance variables (or members, fields - what ever you like to call them) into the `AbstComputer` object so that we can gain access to new fully realised instances of `Abst1`, `Abst2` objects when needed. In other words, all of their own instance variables have been full injected. See [javax.inject.Provider.get()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/inject/Provider.html#get--) - `javax.inject.Provider` is a super-interface of `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`.

```java
...
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;


public class AbstComputer {

    @Inject
    Instance<Abst1> abst1Instance;

    @Inject
    Instance<Abst2 abst2Instance;

    // and three more

    @Produces
    @Computed
    AbstractAbst computeAbst() {
        // arbitrary logic to determine which type of AbstractAbst to create.
        if (useAbst1())
            return abst1Instance.get();
        else if (useAbst2())
            return abst2Instance.get();
        // and three more
        ...
    }


   /**
    * This is here for completeness, but it could be anywhere.
    * It is copied from @theMahaloRecords solution.
    */
   @Produces
   @Named("myString") 
   String lookupMyString() {
      return "test";
   }

}
```

@theMahaloRecords deserves credit for providing a solution for producing a "someCommonString" value.

Note that many developers will prefer declaring a custom `Qualifier` instead of using `@Named` for this purpose because it is fully type safe and there is no danger of typos messing you around, such as `@Named("mystring")`.

Finally, you need to include the qualifier at your injection point:

```java
public class AbstUser {

    @Inject
    @Computed
    AbstractAbst abst;

    public doSomething {
        abst.doSomethingInAbst();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Looks good, just one question: In `computeAbst()`, how can I pass the parameter on which the decision is based upon into the method? So basically, how can I pass my `someDecision` variable from my question into this?

Comment: How are providing this variable? In a property file? As a `-DsomeDecision="foo"` command line parameter? Have you looked at [MicroProfile Config](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config)?

Comment: No its just a local string computed before.

Comment: You need to make this variable available for injection in the way described by @theMahaloRecords

Answer (score 0):

A CDI producer can help with this use case:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
@Qualifier
@interface Value {
    @Nonbinding String value() default "";
}

public class ValueProducer {
    @Produces
    @Value
    @Default
    public String produceValue(InjectionPoint ip) {
        Value val = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Value.class);
        // get the value somehow, for this example we return value provided with annotation
        return val.value();
    }
}

public class Abst1 extends AbstractAbst {
    @Inject
    public Abst1 (@Value("value1") String someCommonString) {
        super(someCommonString);
    }
}

public class Abst2 extends AbstractAbst {
    @Inject
    public Abst2 (@Value("value2") String someCommonString) {
        super(someCommonString);
    }
}
```